# How to further specify what workbook is being referred to

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA form program that consults two different workbooks for two separate functions.  When I run the first function, it runs well, then I run the second function, and it references a background workbook, and runs fine- then when I try to run the first program again, I get a 'subscript out of range' error.  How could I further specify this code to go back to the original workbook?

```
Worksheets("Modified Item Extract").Range("$A$1:$CL$293662").AutoFilter     Field:=1, Criteria1:="" & PBH.Value
```

Comment: Hard to tell with only one line of code, but you need to get references to the workbooks and use the worksheets property of the collected object instead of using the global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest, even if longest is to always define the workbooks and worksheets when using Ranges and Cells later on.

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Sub yourSubName()


Set wb1 = Workbooks("Your_Workbook_Name")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Modified Item Extract")

' do the same for setting wb2 and ws2

ws1.Range("$A$1:$CL$293662").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="" & PBH.Value

End Sub
```